# Multiple CSV files to PHP Array -

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv

i have some problems with CSV files.
I have about 50 csv files, all looks the same like this below.

I need to import them into Php array - (later i put them into js var, and use in diagrams)
But the CSV dont looks like should do (i cant change it) - It have some data at top (first 10 lines) - i need to use them in different places (just show them - like "Kategoria:";"ROLNICTWO, LEŚNICTWO I ŁOWIECTWO"; - is a title)

```
"Okres sprawozdawczy:";"Dane roczne";
"Kategoria:";"ROLNICTWO, LEŚNICTWO I ŁOWIECTWO";
"Grupa:";"SKUP PRODUKTÓW ROLNYCH";
"Podgrupa:";"Skup produktów na 1 ha użytków rolnych";
"Wymiary:";"Wykaz produktów, Lata";

"Kod";"Jednostka terytorialna";"buraki cukrowe";"buraki cukrowe";"buraki cukrowe";"buraki cukrowe";
"2010";"2011";"2012";"2013";
"[kg]";"[kg]";"[kg]";"[kg]";
"1100000000";" ŁÓDZKIE";"278";"355";"363";"333";
"1140000000";" MAZOWIECKIE";"247";"250";"286";"348";
"2120000000";" MAŁOPOLSKIE";"67";"87";"114";"127";
"2240000000";" ŚLĄSKIE";"168";"218";"245";"281";
"3060000000";" LUBELSKIE";"1139";"1170";"1235";"1346";
"3180000000";" PODKARPACKIE";"249";"208";"342";"404";
"3200000000";" PODLASKIE";"6";"30";"5";"0";
"3260000000";" ŚWIĘTOKRZYSKIE";"479";"482";"337";"534";
"4080000000";" LUBUSKIE";"184";"141";"264";"229";
"4300000000";" WIELKOPOLSKIE";"1102";"1412";"1485";"1532";
"4320000000";" ZACHODNIOPOMORSKIE";"522";"830";"909";"642";
"5020000000";" DOLNOŚLĄSKIE";"1044";"1045";"1274";"1136";
"5160000000";" OPOLSKIE";"1392";"1386";"2113";"1660";
"6040000000";" KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE";"1588";"2040";"2272";"2252";
"6220000000";" POMORSKIE";"624";"748";"724";"879";
"6280000000";" WARMIŃSKO-MAZURSKIE";"153";"150";"163";"167";
```

How i can print them as array - to looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
      (
      [0] Okres sprawozdawczy
      [1] Dane roczne
      )
[1] => Array
      (
      [0] Kategoria
      [1] ROLNICTWO, LEŚNICTWO I ŁOWIECTWO
      )
[2] => Array
      (
      [0] Grupa:
      [1] SKUP PRODUKTÓW ROLNYCH
      )
```

etc. first 5 lines of CSV lines.

But later from line 7 (6 is empty) - line 7,8,9 is one header..

```
"Kod" - its "1100000000"
"Jednostka terytorialna" - its "ŁÓDZKIE"

"buraki cukrowe","2010","[kg]" - "278"
"buraki cukrowe","2011","[kg]" - "355"
"buraki cukrowe","2012","[kg]" - "363"
"buraki cukrowe","2013","[kg]" - "333"
```

- 3 headers for one data, so i need i think something like that:

```
[6] => Array ([0] buraki cukrowe => Array ([0] 2010 => Array ([0] kg => Array ([0] 278)
```

Where the "278" is data what i need to use and put in to JS VAR.
Im not sure its good way to do this, please help me out..

Comment: You need to show us some code on how you get the data andput it in an array..

Comment: `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));` : http://php.net/str_getcsv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you set this file on variable, you can use file_get_content() like this

```
$csvData = file_get_contents('your_file.csv');
```

you can do it for all the files you need to add

After you have your $csvData you just have to explode and chunk it like this

```
$explodedCsvData = explode(';',$csvData);
$chuckedCsvData = array_chunk($explodedCsvData,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could do the trick :

```
$file = fopen('your-file.csv');
$header = true;
$headers = [];
$data = [];
while($line = fread($file)) {
    if($line === '') { // Transition from headers to columns info
        $header = false;
        $line = fread($file);
        $label = explode(';', $line);
        $l = count($label);
        $year = array_pad(explode(';', fread($file)), -$l, null);
        $unit = array_pad(explode(';', fread($file)), -$l, null);
        $column = [];
        for($i=0; $i<$l; ++$i) {
            $column[] = [
                'label' => $label[$i],
                'year' => $year[$i],
                'unit' => $unit[$i]
            ];
        }
    }
    elseif($header) { // Still in the first lines
        $headers[] = explode(';', $line);
    }
    else { // After the columns parsing
        $data[] = explode(';', $line);
    }
}
fclose($file);
```